# Why is Process automatically finding my .exe on the Desktop? How can I specify a fixed/non-flexible path instead?

Tags: c#

I launch an executable in the usual way:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\someDirectory\";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "ConsoleProgram.exe";
p.Start();
```

Currently, the executable is not in `C:\someDirectory\`, so I want the above to fail due to an executable that was not found.

Instead, what it does is that it, for some reasons, locates a different executable by the same name on my Desktop! (I know this because if I rename the .exe on the Desktop, the software complains about a .exe that wasn't found.) How can I prevent this behavior, and enforce a particular path and no other path?

Comment: Maybe the desktop is in the path env variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the complete path info to FileName.

Answer (score 2):

> When UseShellExecute is false, the WorkingDirectory property is not
>   used to find the executable. Instead, it is used by the process that
>   is started and only has meaning within the context of the new process.

Here you setting UseShellExecute to false, WorkingDirectory means absolutely nothing, so you'll have to use the absolute path as FileName.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the `Filename` to the path of the file?
Like this:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\someDirectory\ConsoleProgram.exe";
```